# What is the adhesive used to attach the gasket to the hood?

Tags: body

The Gasket that seals around my hood has come loose. There is the residue of an adhesive on the painted metal and the rubber gasket.  What is this likely to be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[3M Weatherstrip adhesive](http://3mcollision.com/3m-super-weatherstrip-and-gasket-adhesive-08002-yellow.html) is the way to go.  I assume you've checked to ensure that it originally was glued, and not clipped in.  Some rubber gaskets use small plastic pins inserted into a hole in the rubber that snap into the door.